# Shouldn't parallel and parallelism tags be merged?

Tags: discussion

There are two tags which look similar to me: [parallel](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parallel) [parallelism](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parallelism).
There are 4 questions tagged with [parallel](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parallel) and 3 different questions tagged with [parallelism](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parallelism).

Answer (score 1):

OK by me. They're synonyms on SO, pointing to `parallel-processing`, but that doesn't quite seem right here. `parallel` seems canonical.